# Why is it necessary to break conformal invariance of the electromagnetic action to generate seeds for primordial magnetogenesis?

Tags: cosmology, magnetic-fields, conformal-field-theory, magnetohydrodynamics

A large number of mechanisms whereby magnetic fields are generated in the early universe involve the breaking of the conformal invariance of the electromagnetic action. Why is it so? What is the problem with a conformally invariant electromagnetic action in regards to primordial magnetogenesis?